# BitLocker activated on it's own after Windows 10 update

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, bitlocker

I got my user a new laptop two months ago (HP EliteBook 850 G7) with Windows10 Pro and one SSD drive. I installed all the important software, never set up Bitlocker, don't think I was even prompted to do so. This morning user installed Windows updates through settings and rebooted. After that C drive was locked by BitLocker.

I can't roll back updates (blocked by BitLocker), recovery key is not uploaded to users Microsoft account, I do have access to CMD after boot but all BitLocker related commands print out error that says it's locked by BitLocker or require password to use. I tried using both Microsoft account and local password.

This user is quite tech savvy, I really doubt he would create a BitLocker recovery key on his own without reporting it or on accident.

After checking BitLocker status:

manage-bde -status :C

Volume C: [Label Unknown]

[Data Volume]

Size: Unknown GB

BitLocker Version: 2.0

Conversion Status: Unknown

Percentage Encrypted: Unknown%

Encryption Method: XTS-AES 128

Protection Status: Unknown

Lock Status: Locked

Identification Field: Unknown

Automatic Unlock: Disabled

Key Protectors:

Numerical Password

TPM

I hope I'm not posting in wrong format. I really took my time looking for solutions but at this point I'm afraid to lose all data. Microsoft support sends me to HP, they send me to vendor. Everyone blames someone else and/or tells me it's "impossible".

Let me know if you need more details or even know where and how I can find them to post here...

Comment: **BitLocker never activates on it's own.** BitLocker cannot be activated without a user guided prompt that instructs the user to backup the recovery key.  Without the passphrase and/or the recovery the only option is to reinstall Windows.  The user should be able to suspend BitLocker protection and/or disable it provided the device has a TPM and BitLocker is configured to use it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. TPM is the place that I started looking in now, I'll keep on trying. I do not share your confidence about BitLocker not turning on, besides working on riddiculous issues on Windows machines before, I can see I'm not the only one with this problem. Issue seems most prevalent on Dell and HP laptops.

Comment: Isn't Bitlocker enabled by default on HP machines that support Modern Standby?

Comment: Where does it store recovery key then?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - You might be thinking about Device Encryption.  Even if BitLocker was enabled by default, that does not match the author's description, where it just magically was enabled.  I am fairly confident that it was not magically enabled.

Comment: The web is full of questions about Bitlocker becoming activated after Windows updates.

Comment: Tried solutions found here, but it keeps printing same error message about beeing blocked by BitLocker

https://betanews.com/2021/02/16/kb4535680-update-bitlocker-problems-windows-10/

Comment: "BitLocker automatic device encryption starts during Out-of-box (OOBE) experience. However, protection is enabled (armed) only after users sign in with a Microsoft Account or an Azure Active Directory account. Until that, protection is suspended and data is not protected."   

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/oem-bitlocker


Where does it store the key if it's enabled by default and it's not visible on user Microsoft account?